# How can I add _document.js or _app.js in Next.js 13?

Tags: next.js, next-router

how can I add **_document.js** or **_app.js** when working with Next.js and the Src/app/pages.js file?

I attempted to add a **'pages'** folder in Next.js inside my **'src'** folder, but it is not functioning as expected.

[image: pic]

Comment: pages should be outside the `app` directory, inside `src`

Comment: pages is not inside app directory

Comment: Is it possible to add _document and _app directly inside app folder ?

Comment: If you're using the `app` directory, `_document` and `_app` files are replaced by the root `layout` file.

Comment: Okay, so they are not usable. For example, to add metadata or a script, do I have to do it directly within the layout?